# How to return values from SQL server database within intervals

Tags: sql-server, date, return, intervals

Hi I have an SQL server database with 3 columns `Activity[start_date(datetime),end_date(datetime),title(string)]`
 and I wish to count for a whole year, how many activities have start_date in each month, I mean I would like a return of 12 values(12 months) that count the activities within the months, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an index on `start_date` and/or if you need to include months in the result even if there was no activity in that month, you might consider this one:

```
DECLARE @year INT;
SET @year = 2012;

;WITH n AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (12) m = DATEADD(MONTH, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY name)-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @year-1900, 0))
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY name
)
SELECT [Month] = n.m, ActivityCount = COUNT(t.title) 
FROM n 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.unspecified_table_name AS t
  ON t.start_date >= n.m
  AND t.start_date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, n.m)
GROUP BY n.m
ORDER BY [Month];
```

(If you don't want a row when there were zero activities in a given month, then change `LEFT OUTER` to `INNER`.)

Comment: yup, this is what I wanted, to include month that have 0 activities, thanks

Comment: We stinkin' need [that row-number-generating function](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/258733/add-a-built-in-table-of-numbers)!

Answer (score 0):

```
select month(start_date) as Month, count(*) as Count
from Activity
where year(start_date) = 2011 
group by month(start_date)
order by month(start_date)
```

Comment: Just an observation, this will only return 12 rows if there was at least one activity in each month.